# FTP gives an error 550 but file permissions are the same

Tags: windows, permissions, ftp

Setup:

- Windows Server 2008 R2 with updates.
- Filezilla FTP Server 0.9.60 (for LAN use only)

Clients:

- Total Commander 10
- WinSCP 5.17

I have two files in the same folder. I can overwrite one of them via FTP and the other one I can't. I get error 550 "Could not open file for writing" in both clients.

I compared file permissions with **icacls** and they are exactly the same. The user on behalf of which Filezilla Server is running, has full rights to the folder and to both files.

I **can** rename the *bad* file via FTP client, but not overwrite it.

The problem is actually bigger than just one file, I have a lot of files on this server with the same problem.

What else should I check?

Answer (score 1):

The problem turned out to be in the "read only" file attribute